# Find the coordinates

Tags: calculus

Find the coordinates of the point on the curve $y=x^3$ where $x \geq 0$, closest to the point $(0,4)$.

How can this be solved by using derivatives?

Comment: Do you know the formula for distance?

Comment: Is the answer $(1.5874,4)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always for such minimization exercises.

(1) Determine what you want to minimize: For $x \in \mathbf R$, the distance of $(x,x^3)$ to $(0,4)$ is given by 
$$ d(x) := \sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (x^3 - 4)^2} $$
As $d$ attains its minimum exactly where $d^2$ does (as $d$ is non-negative), we can also minimize 
$$ m(x) := d^2(x) = x^2 + (x^3 - 4)^2 $$
(2) Find the critical points of $m$, that is, the roots of $m'(x) = 0$.

(3) Find the $m$-values at the critical points, the one with the lowest $m$-value is your solution.